# how to edit large json files with pandas?

Tags: json, pandas

I have a 200mb txt file which includes roughly about 25k JSON files (metadata and the content of newspaper articles). Now i want to manipulate the data so that the file is smaller and it only contains such data which is relevant for my analysis (only 3 out of 16 columns).

Question:

How to delete/drop columns in pandas dataframe and safe these changes to the .json file?

JSON:

```
{"_version_":1609422219455234049,

"content": " abc ",

"docType":"shNews",

"id":"SNW_000050a3-38c6-4794-8e73-3ab3464be248",

"publishDate":"2017-08-16T16:01:018Z",

"stakeholderId":482,

"status":"BlackListed",

"systemDate":"2017-08-16T17:42:010Z"

"tags2":"type_de_Institution;subtype_de_Administration;industry_de_Staat;continent_de_Europa;country_de_Deutschland;level_de_National;highrelevance_eu_0;"

,"title":"Waffen schaffen keine Sicherheit. Von Außenminister Sigmar Gabriel",

"url":"http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/sid_A5AB4A9D659FF8612B357392137BE7EB/DE/Infoservice/Presse/Interviews/2017/170816-BM_Rheinische_Post.html"}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

articles=pd.read_json('/Users/Flo/export_harnisch.json', lines=True, orient='columns')

print (type (articles))

df = pd.DataFrame(articles)

df[df['tags2'].str.contains('country_de_Deutschland')==True]
```

i already tried this:

```
df.to_json ("example_name.json")
```

The actual result of the line i tried is a json file which is larger than the original file and atom cannot read it out. Moreover the changes i made in the dataframe (del/drop of columns) are not applied to the .json file on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_json('/Users/Flo/export_harnisch.json', lines=True, orient='columns')

# read_json should convert things into dataframe already
print(type(articles))

# you forgot to re assign df
df = df[df['tags2'].str.contains('country_de_Deutschland')==True]

df.to_json("example_name.json")
```